# jQuery Mobile Icons not showing in Android 2.3

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using jQuery Mobile of version 1.4.2 and used the following code to show an icon

```
<button data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></button>
```

This is working properly in Android 4.0 and in Firefox Browser but not in Android 2.3

Comment: Do you use locally saved files of JQuery Mobile .js, .css and images? Also add 4 spaces before <button in your post to show this line

Comment: It is work fine in my android device v 2.3.6.

Comment: Yes Regent, I've linked the locally saved only  ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code it is working fine in my `android device v 2.3.6`. If you still feel it is not working please try this one. Use `class="ui-icon-home" instead of data-icon="home". It is added new version of JQM(1.4.2)`

```
<button class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting files locally you should use:

```
jquery.mobile.icon-1.4.3.min.css
```

You should also use the Image folder.